# Drupal 8 with Node.js (integration module vs headless drupal)

Tags: node.js, drupal-8

Let's say I'm running a node.js server that loads my app/page. My Node.js server gets content from Drupal 8 via Restful Service that serves entities.. Is this a common practice. Would it be acceptable to authenticate the user in node.js and encrypt username + password in a nodejs session? Then on every request to Drupal 8, I pass username:password in a Basic Auth header over SSL/TLS?

Or is it better to use Drupal Node.js integration module?

The idea is to have a Service Oriented Architecture and use Drupal as a CMS only, and leave everything else for Node.js, where node interacts with all these services and Others (non-drupal) over REST...

Am I heading in a right direction? Does anyone have any experience with this kind of setup?

Comment: seems crazy, why wouldn't you let Drupal serve pages, that is what it is designed to do...it has built in routing and all sorts of other stuff that it seems like you are missing out on by pulling the data to Node JS...what is it that you hope to accomplish by using a RESTful setup?

Comment: I'm looking to decouple the application and have an isomorphic app. Run react on the server and the browser. And just use Drupal as a CMS. Something like Contentful https://www.contentful.com/

Comment: I'm open to suggestions or/and criticism...

Comment: sounds reasonable if you have a certain goal in mind rather than just using node js for the heck of it :D

Comment: sounds like you aren't sure what use cases you're aiming to be successful at. try drawing some diagrams of the different approaches and then pick. this is a purely opinion based question

Answer (score 0):

Node.js & NPM are required to run JavaScript application development frameworks like React, Angular, Vue, Gatsby, Ember, etc. where programmers are using JSON API & GraphQL to build custom applications with Drupal as the backend under the decoupled CMS approach.

Consider it was very common on Drupal 7 for PHP developers to put custom code in a theme that needed to be processed by PHPTemplate on runtime. When converting a complex Drupal 7 website to Drupal 8, it may be better to optimize it through a Node.js solution using React, Gatsby, or Vue vs. rewriting the theme under the Twig/Synfony2 framework. Drupal page load speeds should be better with the React/Vue/Gatsby + GraphQL approach over PHP themes.

Answer (score -1):

Why not setup nginx or some other proxy, to route certain actions to drupal, and others to nodejs?

EDIT: More elaboration as requested:

In nginx plus there is a module called  ngx_http_auth_request_module, I think from what i've read its possible to use this module to authenticate as described in the posters question.

https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-plus-authenticate-users/

> How would you persist the session and state between the two systems?

The following steps could be the proposed solution: 
1.) Login through nginx (a login page is presented), 
2.) nginx sends request to back-end Daemon for authentication (in your case an ldap service), 
3.) import an ldap module into drupal to authenticate to the same credentials, 
4.) Forward the credentials to drupal
5.) import an ldap module into your nodejs project to authenticate to the same credentials, 
6.) Forward the credentials to node
7.) the cookie for authentication is handled by nginx authentication, and both services based on a reverse proxy can be accessed without any pass through via nodejs.

> Let's say node.js has to integrate with other systems

In this case node.js should have a master account where it doesnt need login credentials, and all permission checking could be done via this master account (can you provide an example scenario where accessing drupal directly would require some interaction with node?).

Comment: Could you elaborate? How would you persist the session and state between the two systems? Let's say node.js has to integrate with other systems.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a resource description for handling authentication from nginx into node and drupal, it may be that you have to modify the python code they mention in the article to interact with drupals rest login mechanism if it doesnt use the proposed username:password base64 encoded mechanism, this shouldn't be difficult to do.

Comment: You could share modules between Server and Browser.